# Java SMTP Authentication only when required

Tags: java, smtp

How do we use java mail API so that SMTP authentication is done only when needed.
For example, if mail.smtp.auth property is set to true, authentication is done even when it is not required by the SMTP server.

Do I need to first send mail without password, catch exception  and based on exception send mail with password?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Surely, if you have the means of doing authentication you should just do it.  Ditto for using a secure channel to talk to the server.  Also, I've never heard of someone configuring an SMTP server with *optional* authentication.  Why would you do that?

Comment: Internal-Internal domain emails are not authenticated in the system i am working with. Hence the requirement. May be strange But is there anyway of doing it.

Comment: Does that "are not" mean "cannot be authenticated" or "don't need to be authenticated"?  In the latter case, best practice would be to authenticate them anyway.

Comment: Yes authentication is best way. no doubt. In my case I don't have control on Mail Server settings that are configured. For example, the mail server can have local-local domain - no authentication and local-external domain with authentication. I've a real scenario like this. I am talking about that specific case. What is the best way of doing it.

Comment: you did not answer my question.

Comment: I don't have control implied that it is upto the user who use the software. By the way we are too much dwelling into same point.

Answer (score 0):

> if mail.smtp.auth property is set to true, authentication is done even
>   when it is not required by the SMTP server.

It is rather hard to believe in the existence or utility of an SMTP server that doesn't require authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But is there any way we can do this?

Comment: @Ramana it's not an interesting question until you provide an existence proof, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> I don't have control implied that it is upto the user who use the software.

The simple solution is to allow the user to turn on / off the use of the configured authentication details.  There are a number of them, including some that enable / disable authentication.

Beyond that, you are out of luck.  You will need to implement your own SMTP provider behavior, either by creating a subclass, or by starting from scratch.  Alternatively, catch the exception and retry.

Your particular mode of operation is simply not supported.

---

For what it is worth, I think that the javamail implementors did the right thing in not supporting this use-case, whether or not they did it deliberately.  It would encourage mail server implementors to be sloppy about security, and end users to play silly games with email spoofing.